# Express, How to load in JS files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I have the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('./index');
});

io.on('connection',(socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

And the following directory structure:

[image]

When I make a request to the server on localhost:3000 I get returned the HTML which is what I want. However, what I don't understand is that the browser fails to load my JS file. Here is my `HTHL`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="/public/script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    test
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error in the console:

> localhost/:5 GET http://localhost:3000/public/script.js 404 (Not Found)
>
> localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/public/script.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Why is chrome unable to download and execute my Javascript file?

Comment: The line `<script src="./public/script.js"></script>` is searching for script.js on a folder called public inside public, try changing it to `<script src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: Use `<script src="/public/script.js"></script>`

Comment: Your solution works Pedro Henrique, didn't know the browser tried to download the JS files relative to the send HTML file, not the root URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your static files route. Adding some route.

`app.use('/public', express.static('public'))`

instead

`app.use(express.static('public'));`